# how to fill .xml document using rapidxml C++

Tags: c++, rapidxml

I am trying something like this,

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "rapidxml.hpp"
//#include "rapidxml_iterators.hpp"
#include "rapidxml_print.hpp"
#include "rapidxml_utils.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace rapidxml;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    std::ofstream theFile ("trial.xml");
    xml_document<> doc;
    xml_node<>* decl = doc.allocate_node(node_declaration);
    decl->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("version", "1.0"));
    decl->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("encoding", "UTF-8"));
    doc.append_node(decl);
    xml_node<>* root = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "page");
    root->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("xmlns", "http://ALTEC-Center.org/xsd/ocr-annotation-1-0.xsd"));
    root->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("Number of lines", "10"));
    doc.append_node(root);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        //char  buf1[8];
        //std::sprintf(buf1, "%d", i);
        xml_node<>* child = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "line");
        child->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("Index",std::to_string(i).c_str()));
        root->append_node(child);

        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            xml_node<>* child1 = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "word");
            child1->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("Index",std::to_string(j).c_str()));
            child1->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("x","0.0"));
            child1->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("y","0.1"));
            child1->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("width","0.2"));
            child1->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("hight","0.3"));
            child1->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("word","محمد"));
            child->append_node(child1);
        }
    }
    theFile << doc;
    theFile.close();
    doc.clear();

    return 0;
}
```

but the output is as follows,

```
<line Index=" ">
    <word Index=" " x="0.0" y="0.1" width="0.2" hight="0.3" word="محمد"/>
    <word Index=" " x="0.0" y="0.1" width="0.2" hight="0.3" word="محمد"/>
    <word Index=" " x="0.0" y="0.1" width="0.2" hight="0.3" word="محمد"/>
    <word Index=" " x="0.0" y="0.1" width="0.2" hight="0.3" word="محمد"/>
    <word Index=" " x="0.0" y="0.1" width="0.2" hight="0.3" word="محمد"/>
    <word Index=" " x="0.0" y="0.1" width="0.2" hight="0.3" word="محمد"/>
    <word Index=" " x="0.0" y="0.1" width="0.2" hight="0.3" word="محمد"/>
    <word Index=" " x="0.0" y="0.1" width="0.2" hight="0.3" word="محمد"/>
</line>
```

and I want "index" attribute = the iterator value of the loop "i" and "j" like

```
<word Index="0" x="0.0" y="0.1" width="0.2" hight ="0.3" word="محمد"/> //j=0
<word Index="1" x="0.0" y="0.1" width="0.2" hight="0.3" word="محمد"/>  //j=1
<word Index="2" x="0.0" y="0.1" width="0.2" hight="0.3" word="محمد"/>
<word Index="3" x="0.0" y="0.1" width="0.2" hight="0.3" word="محمد"/>
```

and so on.
In the previous example I just tried to use the loop parameter as it is but later I want to fill the attributes with something like `word[i][j]`, how could I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You're tripping over one of the most common rapidxml problems: When you build an XML document in this way, RapidXML doesn't make copies of the string data you provide, it just stores pointers to them. (This is a big part of what makes it Rapid).

So when you use this

```
child->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("Index",std::to_string(i).c_str()));
```

.. it's storing a pointer to the temporary string returned from `to_string(i)`. This memory will get overwritten, so your resulting XML document will change.

Instead, you should allocate a temporary rapidXml string to hold the text:

```
char * idxStr = doc.allocate_string(std::to_string(i).c_str()); 
child->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("Index", idxStr));
```

You should always do this unless you're using a literal string (eg `"0.3"`)